# How to open Google Fit app programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit

So, I have an app that uses google sign-in and Google Fit apis to register some data on the be, I would also like to open the Google Fit app from the app's settings.

I've already tried to open it using an Intent and passing the Google Fit's app package name but with no luck.

How I could open it programmatically on user's click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that, from android 11, is necessary to declare in the manifest the package names of the apps that our app needs to interact as follows (Google Fit in this case):

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.fitness" />
</queries>
```

and start another activity as in the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70879471/11723014) given by [@soheil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7772174/soheil)

[more on the official docs page](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring)

Answer (score 0):

***hello my friend,***

**First:**
you should use **PackageManager** class from Android

**Second:**

The App that you need to launch must decalare its FirstActivity as
(Intent#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
Or
(Intent#CATEGORY_INFO)
this is not complex these of two category declare in ManifestFile
here is sample ManifestFile of destination App:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mkyong.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="List of Mobile OS"
        android:name=".ListMobileActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="List of Fruits"
        android:name=".ListFruitActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Ok we consider that Google Fit App has at least one of those flags so now by Packagemanger class we can launch that app

Kotlin:

```
val launchIntent =
        packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("package-name")
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this@MainActivity,
            "There is no package available in android",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
```

Java:

```
 Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package-name");
      if (launchIntent != null) {
         startActivity(launchIntent);
      } else {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no package available in     android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

- package manger and those two Flags in manifest of destination app are Key

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. As I sayed I've already tried using the package name and start the activity but with no luck. e.g. your solution fails with the package name of fit app : "com.google.android.apps.fitness" despite the app being already installed on the phone

Comment: so i am sure the problem is in fit app they dont provided those flags inside its manifest files!!!

Comment: Well, false. If you look in the manifest of the Google Fit app you can clearly see those flags